# Building Epiphany SDK on the Parallella with Arch Linux ARM

Tags: linux, epiphany, parallella

I'am trying to build the Epiphany SDK on the Parallella Board running Arch Linux ARM.

I obtained the Arch Linux ARM Image from http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-parallella-latest.tar.gz but there is also another one related to Xilinx http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/xilinx/ArchLinuxARM-2015.10-parallella-rootfs.tar.gz. Creating the SD-Card wasn't the problem. Further I installed the Epiphany SDK like shown here https://github.com/adapteva/epiphany-sdk/wiki/Building-the-SDK, it also runs through.

Building applications from the examples runs through but when I execute 'run.sh' the whole system hangs and i have to poweroff/-on to get SSH-Access again.

Got anyone the eSDK running on the Parallella with Arch Linux ARM and can give me some hints or point out what I have to provide to solve this problem?

Thanks for your time and best regards,

Befedo